# Filestack Upload to S3 Disable ID prefix

Tags: javascript, api, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

When uploading to S3 via the Filestack API, the files have an ID added as a prefix. Is it possible to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to store files **without** the ID.
My first suggestion is always to use the File Handles if possible because you can take advantage of the Filestack CDN and caching. 
If you **DO** choose to use the S3 URLs and don't want the ID, launch the picker with the `disableKey` parameter

Like this

```
client.pick({
  disableKey: true,
  storeTo: 's3',
  path: 'specific/path/'
})
```